# Use the fill handle for vertical data to get it horizontal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

H,
So i have a vertical list of data list of data, 1 in each cell. For example, in cell A2, I have 1, then in cell A3, I have 2, and so on. Is there a way to use the fill handle to 1,2,etc. HORIZONTAL? So like I need In cell A1, I have =A2 and in cell B1, I have = A3 and so on. Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a formula for that. It can't be done with dragging alone.

in B2:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(B1))
```

Drag to the right.

[image]